# Rails remote: true response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem I cannot solve... I am building a rails application and I use remote: true in order to "attache" a photo to a certain attachable model. Although the photo is attached as expected and the JS code I write in "create.js.erb" is in the server's response, it is not executed.... If I copy and paste the response in the browser's console, everything works as expected (which means there is no syntactical error).

If I change the code in create.js.erb (for example "alert('test');) I get the alert...

I am really stuck.

This is my code in create.js.erb:
  $('il.attachements').html('<%= j render partial: "attachements_list", locals: {photos: "#{params[:attachable_id]}"%>');

As I said, I get the response with the generated html, but it is not executed...If I copy and paste it in the console, It does exactly what I want...

Comment: can you give the entire code in create.js.erb

Comment: That's all there is in create.js.erb...

Comment: The button that attaches the photo, is on a fancybox popup. You are supposed to click "add" and the photo to be attached to the (let's say) article. Everything is alright so far. But then, I want to refresh the div that show the attached photos and That's where the problem occures. Although I cannot understand what the problem is :)

Comment: are you using javascipt or rails :remote => true option

Comment: Try wrapping that code in $(document).ready() like this
   
    ```$(document).ready(function(){
      $('il.attachements').html('<%= j render partial: "attachements_list", locals: {photos: "#{params[:attachable_id]}"%>');
    })```

Comment: I am using remote: true.  I will try that now and let you know! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Nope did not work. At the moment I bypassed this "bug" by refreshing the page when I close the fancybox. Althought it's alright since it's for personal use, I still cannot understand why the requested div is not refreshed as it is supposed to do...

Comment: I believe it has to do with javascript, since the server responds as it should. My front-end experience is minimal..

Comment: Use Double quotes. Change html('<%.. ) to html("<%= ... %>");

Comment: This has nothing to do with single or double quotes... + I tried it and it did not have any difference. The problem is that the javascript in create.js.erb (which is the response from the server) is not executed. Tha code in it is correct (I copy and paste the response in the console in firebug and it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution eventually (for anyone who might stuck with something like this).

The problem was that I was trying to make changes in the parent document and not in the popup.

The following change to my code did the trick (I refered to the parent document)

```
     var m = $('ul.attachements',parent.document);
    m.html('<%= j render partial: "attachements_list", locals: {photos: "#{params[:attachable_id]}"%>');
```

Much less complicated thatn I thought. :)